# Detecting select slider change event in jQuery Mobile

Tags: event-handling, jquery-mobile

What is a reliable way to detect change of a select slider in jQuery Mobile? I try to bind a handler to change event of the select control itself, but it fires on initial page display, and then fires multiple times on clicks, and sometimes even on hover (in desktop browser).

The minimal working example of this behaviour is posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/mTjtt/3/

This is probably caused by jQuery Mobile adding more elements to style the select as the flip-toggle, but I can't find the recommended way to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: +1 for good question. Looks like it's event bubbling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May not be the slickest solution but it works
http://jsfiddle.net/mTjtt/4/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but for me it still causes 2-3 alerts on every couple of state changes :( It am checking in Chrome, perhaps it is not a good idea and should be tested on actual mobile? That would be a nightmare to debug, though.

Comment: Weird, I can't get it to reproduce that problem (in Chrome) but that's just in jsfiddle.

Comment: Looks like alert is also affecting the result, so I rewrote it to use a simulated console here http://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/mTjtt/20/, and your solution does work! While the bug in jQuery Mobile is still present, we will use this approach, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/KCQ4Z/14/
- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/KCQ4Z/70/ (using [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) )

JS:

```
$('#my-slider').change(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var myswitch = $(this);
    var show     = myswitch[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? true:false;

    if(show) {            
        $('#show-me').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#first-me').fadeOut();
    } else {            
        $('#first-me').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#show-me').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" class="type-home"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div class="content-primary"> 
            <p>The flip toggle switch is displayed like this:</p> 
            <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                <label for="slider">Flip switch:</label> 
                <select name="slider" id="my-slider" data-role="slider"> 
                    <option value="off">Off</option> 
                    <option value="on">On</option> 
                </select> 
            </div> 
            <div id="first-me">
                <p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>  
            </div>
            <div id="show-me" class="hidden">
                <p>
                    Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet bresaola velit laboris bacon eiusmod. Id ex short ribs, dolor dolore rump pork belly beef ad ullamco salami labore aute ut. Jowl et in do, fatback jerky salami reprehenderit irure laboris pork loin commodo qui eu. Chuck tri-tip cupidatat, turkey sunt in anim jerky pork belly exercitation bacon. Eu corned beef qui adipisicing, ground round veniam turkey chicken incididunt deserunt. Proident t-bone chuck, non excepteur biltong elit in anim minim swine short loin magna do. Sint enim nisi, minim nulla tongue ut incididunt ground round.
                </p>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I have raised an issue/bug with jQM here:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2188

Comment: Did you check how many times that code is executed? It is called 2-3 times for me. I guess the fact that you do anims slowly prevents one from seeing this. Here is a simple change to your live code to see this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/KCQ4Z/59/

Comment: At first I didn't see it but it's the jQuery version 1.6.2 that's causing this. 1.6.1 is fine in my testing. maybe you should use the click event instead of the change event

Comment: hmm click event doesn't seem to fire. testing

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this first thing tomorrow!

Comment: In your latest code, with stopPropagation, I get exactly the same result as before - there are several events called :(

Comment: what version of jQuery are you running? And is there anymore to your function?

Comment: 1.6.2, and there is much more to my function. But I see this multiple trigger behaviour in the JSFiddle example that I shared - and in yours too (it may also depend on where you click in the control). I think I'll just have to check if the state of the toggle is different from a stored variable - and if so, then I'll know it has changed.

Comment: Hmm looks like this might be a bug, I updated my question with the jQM issue for them to take a look at things. If you find anything that works please post back

Comment: Hopefully this fixes it in 1.0RC1: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/4fa6ccdc0d8625f58e43e446f24bc4e65f87cb1d I will test it later today.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
$( ".mySliders" ).slider({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).bind('change', function () {
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

!Do not put type="range" to your input tags , put type="text" instead.

Since you are calling slider function manually.

Comment: It doesn't work any different from .change binding, tried it on the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mTjtt/127/ Did you actually test it?